# C++ Incorrect display of function parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

Salutations,

I've managed to get this program to read from an input file and display correctly the cost of the cheapest textbooks in a given subject, but it gives me an incorrect display of which textbook is the cheapest. The Program always says textbook1 is the cheapest even when textbook2 or textbook3 is the cheapest. I have a feeling I may have passed my parameters incorrectly. Below is my code and an attachment of the output of my program. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[Output of Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXScA.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

void print_output(int text_num, double t1, double t2, double t3, double tot, 
int num, double cheap_one);

using namespace std;

int main() {

// define variables
string  store_name;
string subject;

// define variables

ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;

string Biology, Chemistry, English, Computer, Mathematics;
double text1, text2, text3;
double total1;
double small;
double text_num = 1;
double num = 1;


cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

// print titles here like dereks bookstore and the subjects plus 
text/cheapest 

cout << "Derek's Bookstore" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Subject\t" << setw(5) << "    Text 1\t" << "Text 2\t" << "Text 3\t" 
<< "Total\t" <<
    "    Cheapest/Amount\t" << endl;
cout << endl;

inData.open("first_project_data.txt");
if (!inData) {
    cout << "\nCannot open input file." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

inData >> subject;

while (inData) {
    //cout << "\n\n**at beginning" << subject << endl << endl;
    inData >> text1 >> text2 >> text3;

    // calculate totals

    total1 = text1 + text2 + text3;

    // find out the cheapest book (use if statement )
    small = text1;
    if (text1 > text2)
        small = text2;
    if (small > text3)
        small = text3;

    // call the print function

    print_output(text_num, text1, text2, text3, total1, num, small);

    text_num++;



    inData >> subject;

}

// output the last total line

cout << "Totals     " << "100.00" << "\t" << "105.00" << "  110.00" << "  
315.00" << "           ****N/A****" <<  endl;
cout << endl;
//close files

inData.close();
outData.close();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void print_output(int subject, double t1, double t2, double t3, double tot, 
int num, double cheap_one) {
char text_name[9], subject_name[12];

switch (subject) {

case 1: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Biology");
    break;
case 2: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Chemistry");
    break;
case 3: strcpy_s(subject_name, "English");
    break;
case 4: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Computer");
    break;
case 5: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Mathematics");
    break;

}


switch (num) {


case 1: strcpy_s(text_name, "text1");
    break;
case 2: strcpy_s(text_name, "text2");
    break;
case 3: strcpy_s(text_name, "text3");
    break;
}
cout << setw(12) << left << subject_name << t1 << "\t" << t2 << "\t" << t3 
<< "\t" << tot << "\t\t"
    << text_name << "/$ " << cheap_one << endl;
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You never set `num` to anything but `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Im aware but I must define num or otherwise there is just gibberish in the output. I tried to make an if statement but same problem.

Comment: You shouldn't use `double` for indices, use integrals instead.

Comment: Yes, because the value that gets copied into `text_name` depends directly on `num` in `print_output`, which is passed from `num` in `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block

```
if (text1 > text2)
    small = text2;
if (small > text3)
    small = text3;
```

Needs to also update `num`, otherwise you will always pass `num = 1` and the `switch(num)` statement in `print_output` will always pick `case 1`. You can fix by changing the above block to

```
if (text1 > text2) {
    small = text2;
    num = 2;
}
if (small > text3) {
    small = text3;
    num = 3;
}
```

Comment: Hi ghost, thanks a lot my friend. I can pass this assignment in now :)

Comment: @AlCapwned No problem, glad to help